# Signalr + unity DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, signalr

I have used Signalr in my MVC4 project succesfully by the conventional method by setting up a normal hub, including the JS file `/signalr/hubs` and it works.

Now I am trying to setup DI with unity:

In `Global.asax`

```
UnityContainer = Bootstrapper.Initialise();
var unityDependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);

// Used for MVC
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(unityDependencyResolver);

// Used for SignalR
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);

RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

`Bootstrapper.cs`

```
public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
{
    var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

    unityContainer.RegisterType<IUsers, Users>();

    unityContainer.RegisterType<ChatHub>(new InjectionFactory(CreateMyHub));

    return unityContainer;
}

private static object CreateMyHub(IUnityContainer p)
{
    return new ChatHub(p.Resolve<IUsers>());
}
```

And the hub:
public class UserHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IUsers  _users;

```
public ChatHub(IUsers users)
{
    _users = users;
}

public void Send(String message)
{
    Clients.All.addMessage(message);
}
```

}

My SignalRUnityDependencyResolver.cs

```
public class SignalRUnityDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container", "Containet cannot be null");
        }
        _container = container;
    }

    public override Object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.Resolve(serviceType) : base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.ResolveAll(serviceType) : base.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```

This is working for non hubs because all dependencies resolve, but now the javascript file `<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>` is not generated anymore.

How can I debug this generation of JS and where could be the culprit?

Comment: Can you post your full `Application_Start` method? Because the order of the setup is important: first the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` should be set after that `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` and only after that the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` should be called.

Comment: The one I posted is what I have, so I will fiddle around with the order.

Comment: This is another way to Inject Unity container in your hub
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30887576/3000736

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in config
EnableJavaScriptProxies = false

the code like this:

```
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,

                EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
            };

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```